# How to patch OpenJDK 9 with Jigsaw integrated?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Before Jigsaw it was quite easy to replace one or several classes in OpenJDK (to perform some test or make a contribution). I could copy an original file from OpenJDK source, for example, `java/util/ArrayList.java` into `src/java/util/`, add any changes I want, then compile it normally (outputting to `mypatch` directory):

```
$ javac.exe src\java\util\ArrayList.java -d mypatch
```

After that I could launch JVM with `-Xbootclasspath/p` to replace original `ArrayList` with the patched one:

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:mypatch MyTestClass
```

However this does not work anymore since Jigsaw integration in Java 9-ea+111. The compilation command reports tons of errors starting like this:

```
src\java\util\ArrayList.java:26: error: package exists in another module: java.base
package java.util;
^
src\java\util\ArrayList.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
                                  ^
  symbol: class AbstractList
src\java\util\ArrayList.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
                   ^
```

And even if I compile with older JDK, then JVM cannot start:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How to make patches for JDK with Jigsaw?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the javac error message you can know that the class you're compiling belongs to the `java.base` module. Now to compile the JDK class you have to specify the module it belongs with `--patch-module` argument:

```
$ javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatch \
      src/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.java
```

Now to replace existing classes with the new ones use `--patch-module <module-name>` JVM argument:

```
$ java --patch-module java.base=mypatch MyTestClass
```

Here we should specify the directory which contains subdirectories named like the corresponding modules. Now everything works as before. You may specify this several times if you patched several modules:

```
$ java --patch-module java.base=mypatch --patch-module java.xml=myxmlpatch MyTestClass
```

Comment: Note that the `-Xpatch` syntax you are using is an old form, that will disappear soon - see [the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-March/007079.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will update the answer once it will change. Seems that currently new form doesn't work for JDK packages.

Comment: @TagirValeev I am getting this error `javac: invalid flag: -Xmodule:jdk.jshell`
I ran the command with, 
`javac -Xmodule:jdk.jshell -d bin/ --source-path src/ src/jdk/jshell/execution/JDIInitiator.java` 
Did I miss something?

Comment: I have found and posted the answer to this question. Thanks

Comment: The `-Xmodule` option was removed - [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658807/2525313) shows how to do it without it.

Comment: @JackDaniels thanks for the hint. I edited my answer in order not to confuse people and made it a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the new solution that works with the released version of jdk 9.

```
javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base \
    src/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.java

java --patch-module java.base=mypatches/java.base ...
```

Source: [Project Jigsaw: Module System Quick-Start Guide](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#xoverride)